# how to create a QT plugin using Meego Touch Framework?

Tags: c++, css, qt, plugins, meego

I'm new to QT plug ins and Meego Touch Framework. My goal is to be able to create a QT plug in that reads CSS files to customize any application loaded in a terminal. So if user wants to customize any application, all he has to do is create a css file and load it. Can somebody give me a jumpstart how to do this using Meego Touch Framework? I have been reading this -> http://meego.com/developers/ui-design-guidelines/handset/ui-customization-guidelines but all I'm getting are the basics...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default meegotouch does support "per application" stylesheets so if i understand your question, its already implemented.